# Use NotifyOSD with i3wm window manager

Tags: unity, notify-osd, i3-wm

I use i3wm as window manager, but something seems to be broken. I want to use NotifyOSD as a notification service, but I  am not able to set it as a default service. At the moment I get ugly blueish angular notofication messages in the top left window corner (maybe dunst). How can I install NotifyOs and set it as default?

Even if I use Unity as WM, NotifyOSD does not work.

Answer (score 5):

I found [this thread](http://crunchbang.org/forums/viewtopic.php?id=23433), which claims (part of) the solution is:

```
sudo aptitude remove --purge dunst
```

**Edit: It works!** After a reboot (login & logout may do it four you), I now have the "old" notifications in the righthand top corner back.

Comment: Thank you very much. This works perfect in Ubuntu 14.04, even so we need to run a notification's daemon in order to have such "old notifications in the righthand top corner" which is solved by using the `gnome-settings-daemon`, just for reference for further visitors, inside your i3WM we can install it via `sudo apt-get install gnome-settings-daemon` and invoke it with `exec gnome-settings-daemon` in our config file which is located on the .i3 folder inside the home folder. Good luck!